# Duvida receber 3 numeros e dizer se o primeiro é igual a soma dos outros dois em LISP

Tags: lisp

Estou fazendo uma função em Lisp que recebe 3 números e diz se o primeiro é igual a soma dos outros dois, o código que cheguei foi esse:

```
(defun maior(n1 n2 n3)
  (if (=(+ n2 n3)n1)
  (format t "~D é maior que ~D e ~D!" n1 n2 n3)
)
```

Porém, ele não esta rodando acredito que o problema seja na sintaxe, eu quero mostrar que a soma de `n2` e `n3` é igual a `n1`.

Comment: No título da pergunta, você diz ter dúvida. Qual é? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/85610/edit) ai sua pergunta e mostre o que já fez e em qual parte está a dúvida.

Comment: Mudei a pergunta amigo.. e coloquei o codigo que esta dando erro na minha duvida.

Comment: Era mto simples, eu tinha esquecido de fechar o if .-. Obrigado pela atenção amigo, sou novo aqui no forum, vou tentar fazer perguntas mais elaboradinhas na próxima, abraços.

Answer (score 2):

Faltou fechar o parêntese do `if`:

```
(defun maior(n1 n2 n3)
  (if (=(+ n2 n3)n1)
      (format t "~D é maior que ~D e ~D!" n1 n2 n3)
  )
)
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/WxYGDn).